# Is there a way to select photos in a specific directory with UIImagePickerController

Tags: ios, camera, photo

I'd like to select photos from a directory in my application's sandbox with UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary as a source, instead of selecting from the standard photo library. Does anyone know if this is possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No its not...Youll have to create your own kind of picker for that

Comment: That's what I was afraid of, oh well, shouldn't be too much trouble to create my own, thanks